# Dynamic references content

Tags: cross-referencing, dynamic

I am trying to redact a document which has a lot of common part, depending only on some values.
Those values are overwritten for each component, but at some point, I make reference to a subsection, with a name depending on a counter.
Everything is fine while I am inside that loop, but if I have to read it after the loop, I always end-up by reading the last counter value (which is normal you would say), but I need to have the value from the moment of its addition.

To give an idea, here is a small part of my document with what I would like to do:

###### Main file

```
\documentclass[10pt,paper=a4,titlepage,twoside=true,openany,]{scrbook}
\usepackage{forloop}            
\usepackage{hyperref}               
\usepackage{lipsum}             
\usepackage{listofitems}        
\usepackage{ninecolors}         
\usepackage{scrhack}            
\usepackage{tabularray}

\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox, functional, varwidth}

\newcounter{CounterSeperator}
\newcounter{CounterCurrentDevElement}

\newcommand{\FileBuffer}{TabulArrayBuffer.tmp}

\setsepchar{\\/;}
\readlist*\DevList{
  Device full name A; DevShortNameA; Device description A\\
  Device full name B; DevShortNameB; Device description B\\
}

\newcommand{\BufferSectionDesc}{}
\newcommand{\CriticKA}{\colorbox{red4}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{K1}}}}
\newcommand{\CriticKB}{\colorbox{brown4}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{K2}}}}
\newcommand{\CriticKC}{\colorbox{violet4}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{K3}}}}
\newcommand{\DefineSectionBuffer}[3] {
  \ifthenelse{#2 = 1}{\renewcommand{#3}{#1 - \CriticKA} }{\renewcommand{#3}{#1}}
  \ifthenelse{#2 = 2}{\renewcommand{#3}{#1 - \CriticKB} }{}
  \ifthenelse{#2 = 3}{\renewcommand{#3}{#1 - \CriticKC} }{}
}

\begin{document}

  \newwrite\FileInstance
  \immediate\openout\FileInstance=\FileBuffer

  \chapter{This is my chapter}
    \label{chap:MyNewChapter}
    \input{./tex/MyNewChapter}

  \immediate\closeout\FileInstance

  \chapter{Summary}
    \label{chap:Summary}
    \begin{longtblr}[evaluate=\fileInput,]{
        colspec = XXc,
      }
      \fileInput{\FileBuffer}
    \end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

###### MyNewChapter.tex file

```
\section{One of my sections}
  \label{sec:MyNewChapter_MySection}

  \forloop[1]{CounterSeperator}{1}{\value{CounterSeperator} < \listlen\DevList[]\par} {
    \input{./tex/DevDescription}
  }
```

###### DevDescription.tex file

```
\stepcounter{CounterCurrentDevElement}
\DefineSectionBuffer{Component \# \arabic{CounterCurrentDevElement}}{\arabic{CounterCurrentDevElement}}{\BufferSectionDesc}
\subsection{\BufferSectionDesc}
  \label{sec:MyNewChapter_MySection_\DevList[\value{CounterSeperator}, 2]_Componenent\arabic{CounterCurrentDevElement}}
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \immediate\write\FileInstance{\arabic{CounterCurrentDevElement} \unexpanded{&} {\nameref{sec:MyNewChapter_MySection_\DevList[\value{CounterSeperator}, 2]_Componenent\arabic{CounterCurrentDevElement}}} \unexpanded{&} {\ref{sec:MyNewChapter_MySection_\DevList[\value{CounterSeperator}, 2]_Componenent\arabic{CounterCurrentDevElement}}} \unexpanded{\\}}
```

So inside the DevDescription.tex, everything is OK, the problem is when the table is added. I have the following behaviour:

- The reference are linked correctly (both for *\ref* and *\nameref*)
- The *\ref* command gives me the correct section values
- The *\nameref* command gives me always the following text "Component # 3 - K3"

I hope I was clear enough, and that someone would be able to help me.

---

**Edit:**
Here is a small screenshot of the table I get from this example
[image: Wrong reference description]

Comment: Sounds like a task and question interesting for this community. However, I suggest to add a little extra to make it compile, when we copy your code(s), so we can analyse and improve your approach. You may find this procedure useful: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you

Comment: Thank you, indeed, I forgot a few package and made a few mistakes when trying to remove all the non essential to the problem. Now it is compiling, and we can see the problem.   I also added a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Fine :) I‘m sure, the more experienced members here will come up with a sound answer. Just allow a little time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem there is one of the timing the name ref is expanded. By default, `gettitlesstring`, which is used by `nameref` (in your MWE, loaded by `hyperref`) does not expand the titles when the label is stored. So, in your MWE, you find the following labels in the `.aux` file:

```
\newlabel{sec:MyNewChapter_MySection_DevShortNameA_Componenent1}{{1.1.1}{1}{\BufferSectionDesc }{subsection.1.1.1}{}}
\newlabel{sec:MyNewChapter_MySection_DevShortNameB_Componenent2}{{1.1.2}{1}{\BufferSectionDesc }{subsection.1.1.2}{}}
```

As you see, `\BufferSectionDesc` is stored unexpanded in the label. So, when you call `\nameref` to fill your "Summary", it will retrieve the value of `\BufferSectionDesc` at that point, which is the last value it had taken up to then.

But you can ask `gettitlestring` to expand the contents of the name reference with:

```tex
\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}
```

(after `hyperref` has been loaded).

With that, you will find in your `.aux` file instead:

```
\newlabel{sec:MyNewChapter_MySection_DevShortNameA_Componenent1}{{1.1.1}{1}{Component \# 1 - \colorbox {red4}{\textcolor {white}{\protect \textbf  {K1}}}}{subsection.1.1.1}{}}
\newlabel{sec:MyNewChapter_MySection_DevShortNameB_Componenent2}{{1.1.2}{1}{Component \# 2 - \colorbox {brown4}{\textcolor {white}{\protect \textbf  {K2}}}}{subsection.1.1.2}{}}
```

And your "Summary":

[image]