# How to get correct exhibit number when referenced

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I have the following tex code:

```
% Define a counter for exhibits
\newcounter{exhibitcounter}

% Define the exhibit command
\newcommand{\exhibit}[2]{%
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{exhibitcounter}
  \section*{Exhibit \theexhibitcounter: #2}
  \label{#1}
}

% Define the reff command to show exhibit number, title, and page
\newcommand{\reffexhibit}[1]{%
  \ref{#1}: \nameref{#1} (page \pageref{#1})%
}
```

Then I define some exhibit:

```
\exhibit{exhibit1}{abcde} {
  \label{exhibit1}
  abcd
}
```

and use:

```
Here, we reference \reffexhibit{exhibit1}
```

Currently, the pdf outputs: `Here, we reference 1: Exhibit 0: abcde (page 3)`

I want to only outputs `Here, we reference 1: abcde (page 3)`. I don't want to avoid this issue by changing the definition of \exhibit to `\section*{#2}`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: *If* I extend your snippets into a presumable simple document, I get expected results. So ideally you should build a full MWE demonstrating this misbehavior since, as things are, we are missing some piece of information which only you hold. Also, you don't need to set `\label{exhibit1}` again `\exhibit` already does that for you.

Comment: But, if my crystal ball is working today, I'd bet you need `\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708059/105447).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @gusbrs yeah thank you, the `\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}` works!

Comment: @gusbrs yeah I guess this perfectly explains. kudos

Comment: @9f241e21 Great you got it working. Next time, consider providing a full MWE to your question. It makes things so much easier and productive for everyone.